# Why does visual studio 2017 Intellisense tell me "identifier cstring is undefined"?

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2017

I upgraded an MFC project to visual studio 2017 and now intellisense complained about `CString`, `CPoint`, `CRec`, `CSize`, `RPC_IF_HANDLE` and many more are "undefined".

The project compiles fine. So what is intellisense missing or looking at a wrong include directory?

Answer (score -1):

I had to hand edit the project *.vcxproj file and replace

```
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)Microsoft.CPP.UpgradeFromVC71.props" />
```

with

```
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)Microsoft.CPP.UpgradeFromVC60.props" />
```